# ConfuserEx Winforms Selfhosted WebAPI

Tags: winforms, asp.net-web-api2, confuserex

I am trying to confuse a Winforms self hosted WebAPI project. 
I am using ConfuserEx UI for an exe and two dll files. No packer and settings to Normal.

When the exe gets confused, I get the following error when executing.

> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: The following errors occurred
>   while attempting to load the app.
>
> No 'Configuration' method was found in class
>   '?????????????????????????????????????????, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Seems that it cannot find the Startup class Configuration method to start the web server.

I am totally new to ConfuserEx.

Thank you

Comment: It seems ConfuserEx confused you.

Comment: It most certainly did.